# How to reply to "congratulations" other than simply saying "thank you"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine someone important congratulated you at work (getting a big client, swiftly solving a burning issue) by email. How can one reply to that in the most formal way possible?

> Thank you for your kind words.

and

> Thank you. I appreciate your kind words.

seem unnatural to me.

Comment: You want to reply *in the most formal way possible* but not to *seem stilted* ?  I'm not sure those requirements are in any way compatible.  FWIW both of your choices seem OK to me.

Comment: I can't say I get it, but some people reply "Thank you. I try."

Comment: This might be more of a question for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ How to deal with compliments seems their sort of thing.

Comment: @StuartF Also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ , since they deal explicitly with professionalism according to their Tour.

Comment: Also, next time you ask, provide the context. A spoken response will differ a lot from a written email, which will in turn differ from a thank you note.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I'd personally go for a simple "thank you", but I was given a task of finding a "fancier" version. 
@HighPerformanceMark I, possibly wrongly, took the "unnatural" part of the definition of "stilted" as the choices I gave seemed correct, but too unnatural.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Great advice. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in a work setting and you want to boost your reputation even more, consider sharing the gratitude with others who were involved or helped.

For example:

> I appreciate your kind words. This was a true team effort and a hard-earned accomplishment.

Comment: Thanks! A great addition. So "I appreciate your kind words" isn't incorrect/unnatural per se?

Comment: Nope, in an email that phrasing is definitely appropriate.

Comment: Please note that this question is inappropriate on ELU, being a far closer match for the other SE sites mentioned in comments.